# Is it considered good practice using too many factories in pytest?

Tags: django, testing, django-rest-framework, pytest, factory-boy

I am trying to write tests for Django/DjangoREST project. I have decided to use pytest. I have poor experience in writing tests for Django projects specifically. So I am confused now.

Here is an example:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_some_view(
    api_client,
    simple_user,
    model1_factory,
    model2_factory,
    ...  # many other model factories
    modelN_factory
):
    # ...
    # creating here other objects that really depends on each other
    # ...
    model2_obj = ...   # model2 object on its own side depends on model3, model4... and so on

    model1_objs = []
    for i in range(10):
        model1_objs.append(model1_factory(some_field=100, some_model2_rel=model2_obj)
    assert len(model1_objs) == 1, "Created items with duplicate `some_field`"
```

As you can see I have too many factories to be used in one test. But looking
at my model structure right now, I can't think of a better way. Is it ok to use so many
factories for one test? Or should I find some issues related to my tables' relations?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main goal of factory_boy is getting rid of fixtures; its typical use case is:

1. Design your `Factory` classes,  which are basically recipes for getting a "realistic" object instance
2. In your test, call only the factories you need, specifying just the parameters for that test case.

As I understand it, pytest fixtures are intended for "setting up the test environment": booting the database, mocking an external service, etc.; creating objects inside the database isn't a good fit for them.

The way I'd write your code would be the following:

```py
# factories.py
import factory
import factory.fuzzy

from . import models

class DivisionFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Division
    name = factory.Faker('company')

class EmployeeFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Employee
    username = factory.Faker('username')
    name = factory.Faker('name')
    employee_id = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'EM199%06d' % n)
    division = factory.SubFactory(DivisionFactory)
    role = factory.fuzzy.FuzzyChoice(models.Employee.ROLES)
    hired_on = factory.fuzzy.FuzzyDate(
        start_date=datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=100),
        end_date=datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=10),
    )
```

We have a factory for an employee, and one for a division - and each employee gets assigned to a division.
Every mandatory field is provided; if we need to make specific factories for some object profiles, this can be added through either subclassing or using [traits](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#traits).

We can now write our tests, passing only the details required for the test:

```py
# tests.py

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_get_new_hire(api_client):
    employee = factories.EmployeeFactory(
        hired_on=datetime.date.today(),
        division__name="Finance",
    )
    data = api_client.get(f'/employees/{employee.username}')
    assert data['division'] == "Finance"
    assert data['orientation_status'] == 'pending'
```

As a side note, wouldn't it make more sense to use Django's test runner directly? It's more finely tuned for Django internals: each test can be natively wrapped in a sub-transaction for performance, the test client provides helpers for in-depth introspection of view results, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although it does not seem that you have answered my question directly (may be it is because I my question is wrong), but I've got the point . I think that I must investigate factory boy.

Comment: Sorry; since the post was tagged `factory-boy`, I assumed your factories where from FactoryBoy ;)   For your initial question, if you go with FactoryBoy, I strongly suggest spending some time defining your factories carefully, describing the relationships through SubFactory, so that you only need to use one or two factories in the test ;)

Comment: Yes, I am using factory boy. And I already spent a good time defining my factories, so everything is OK now.